# Archive all files in Desktop to D Drive using winrar command, Multi Users

Tags: winrar

I would like to use winrar command to archive all files in the desktop to the D drive, the batch files could run in Different PC that means different desktop path depends on the username.

how can I do that please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a command prompt window, run there command **set** and look on list of output environment variables defined by default for your user account on your machine. There is **USERPROFILE** containing path to the user's profile directory of current user with subdirectory `Desktop` which is a standard Windows environment variable. And there is **USERNAME** with name of current user which is also predefined by Windows for each user account.

Then double click on file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of *WinRAR*. This text file is the manual for `Rar.exe` which is the console version of *WinRAR*. By reading this file from top to bottom, it is very easy to create the command line required for your task.

The following command line can be used to compress all files and folders of current user's desktop with exception of empty folders into a RAR archive using good compression to drive D: with name of user and current date in archive file name.

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -agYYYY-MM-DD -cfg- -dh -ed -ep1 -idq -m4 -r -y "D:\Desktop_%USERNAME%_.rar" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"
```

Or another variant always updating same archive file for the user:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Rar.exe" u -cfg- -dh -ed -ep1 -idq -m4 -r -y "D:\Desktop_%USERNAME%.rar" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"
```

It is of course also possible to use *WinRAR* for example in a shortcut file with the appropriate command and switches on command line for the compression with showing compression progress in a GUI window.

Click in *WinRAR* in menu **Help** on menu item **Help topics**. Select help tab **Contents** and open list item *Command line mode*. Read the referenced pages in order as displayed in contents list. The command line for `WinRAR.exe` would be nearly the same as for `Rar.exe`.

Comment: thank you @Mofi your answer was too much helpful with me, I've created a patch file contain all the needs ☻